# React - event.target.getAttribute("id") returns null on IE11

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How to correct for IE11 in this scenario so that I can get the ID from `onClick` in a cross browser compatible way? Works on Chrome, but not on internet explorer which returns null.

```
<button
  id="plus6"
  onClick={ () => plusbuttontoggle(event.target.getAttribute("id")) }
  className="plus-button"> 
    {" "} + {" "}
</button>
```

Comment: Try using a named parameter: `onClick = {e => plusbuttontoggle(e.target...)}`

Comment: no luck there, just throws an error.

Comment: Can you show the code you used and the exact error you got?

Comment: Tested my suggestion and it works fine for me in IE11: `onClick={e => plusbuttontoggle(e.target.getAttribute("id"))`

Comment: @user1088793 the below code doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Read about Refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

You have to be careful when you want to use DOM elements using React.

Answer (score 0):

Get the id in your function like below.

```
<button id="plus6" onClick={plusbuttontoggle} className="plus-button">
  {" "}
  +{" "}
</button>;

function plusbuttontoggle(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id);
};
```